# How to start jQuery toggle collapsed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle

I'm trying to have a jQuery toggle be collapsed by default.

I have read some other examples, but they weren't quite the same as my setup and I couldn't really figure them out.

This is my HTML:

```
<table border="0" width="100%" align="center">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div style="float:right;">
<a style="font-size:10px;" href="#" id="tgloptions">Options</a>

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="options" style="white-space: nowrap; width: 100%;">OPTIONS</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

and current script:

```
$('#tgloptions').click(function () {
    $('#options').toggle('fast');
    return false;
});
```

and [**jsBin**](http://jsbin.com/wamuvaha/1/)

I managed to get the toggle to work fine. I just want it to not be there on page load and there once clicked.

I played around with adding:

```
$('#options').collapse("hide")
```

but couldn't manage to get that bit to work so I removed it.

Comment: use jQuery instead of $

Comment: It's the same thing Bhushan..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep it hidden by adding the line ([jsBin](http://jsbin.com/wamuvaha/3)):

```
$('#options').hide();
```

Comment: cant accept it yet, but you got it =) i knew i was close lol, thank you =)

Comment: @DrCustUmz: Keep in mind that you are loading the options visible first and only hiding them with script after the DOM has loaded. On occasion, depending on size of the DOM and any intermittent "lag" you might see the options flicker. If that becomes noticeable simply start the element in the DOM hidden to begin with in it's intended default state rather than hiding them as an afterthought by adding CSS, similar to this: `#options{ display: none; }`